# Unable to View Google Map in My Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to use Google Map in an android application but I am unable to see the Map when i run the application . The only thing that I can see is a blank view with zoomin - zoomoout sign. I tried many of the stackoverflow solutions but could not get through it. Please help me to get away with this. Thankyou very much.

I followed this link to get the Google Map Key -

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api

My Apps Manifest.xml is as follows -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.surajkumar.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
   <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />                 
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/pin_location"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
    android:name="com.surajkumar.myapp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_tag" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/gmap_apiv2_key" />
  <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

The layout file is as follows -

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:background="@color/honeydew" 
  >
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/yourlocationtxt"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Refresh to get your location"/>

<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/mapsection"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0px"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="4dp">

<fragment
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
<Button
  android:id="@+id/sendsms"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/sendlocationbtntxt" 
  android:background="@drawable/button_style"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity Code is as follows -

```
 package com.surajkumar.myapp;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private GoogleMap peoplesLocMap;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     peoplesLocMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();    
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should change this

```
<fragment
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

to

```
<fragment
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

also add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
in your manifest

Comment: I made these changes but it did not work. Do i need to change anything in the device settings also i am installing the application on my phone directly by copying the .apk file to sd card and then installing it from there. Is there a problem with that

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

to

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

and Add your own permission in menifest

```
<permission
        android:name="yourPackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="yourPackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

thats it

Comment: I made these changes but it did not work. Do i need to change anything in the device settings also i am installing the application on my phone directly by copying the .apk file to sd card and then installing it from there. Is there a problem with that

Comment: whats your phone Android version?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the following in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.surajkumar.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.surajkumar.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

this should be in right before application closing tag:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

change this

```
<fragment
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

to

```
<fragment
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

and to load the map from your activity:

```
GoogleMap gMap;
```

in onCreate:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
gMap = mapFragment.getMap();
```

try going over the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api) you mentioned again to see if you missed something and make sure you generated the key properly because what you described with blank view but zoom in/out signs are showing is a lot of the times key related issue

good luck...

Comment: I tried doing the same but it didnt work. And if there is a problem with my api key then could you please help me in getting the api key correct . what i have done previously to get the api key is as follows

Comment: 1) I got the SHA-1 finger print using the following on windows cmd       keytool -list -v -keystore C:/users/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android                        2) on the link mentioned i navigated to services and turned on Google Maps Api V2                                                           3)Navigated to api access on the left navigation bar and clicked on create new android key

Comment: 4) on the dialog that appears i typed in my SHA-1 fingerprint;com.surajkumar.myapp and clicked on create ,          copied the api key generated and used it in the manifest as mentioned by you  . Now could you please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong and what can I do to resolve this

Comment: what you describe is how you obtain the key...
did you get the output like the example on the link ; "You should see output similar to this:" are you sure you copied the sha1 fingerprint "20 two-digit hexadecimal numbers" . try repeating the process. if it doesnt change anyhing with new key than it's probably not a problem with the key.
i recently went through the same steps and the info on the link did the trick.

Comment: yes i followed the same steps and the output was also same as shown in the link and also i have tried it three times, but its still not working. I dont know what the problem is

Comment: try loading your layout with just the map fragment, see if that helps, also try replacing: 
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" with this :
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: tried ! did not work , still the same old blank screen with zoom in/out sign